# Android Customized Barchart

Tags: java, android, charts

I need to create a chart like this picture bellow in Android.
[image: customized chart picture]

and I am already aware of [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart) and [AndroidHelloCharts](https://github.com/lecho/hellocharts-android) libraries. but none of them are capable of drawing such thing.

do you know any way to create a chart like this?
please explain and at least suggest me some tutorials or articles that are related to what I am about to do.

thank you

Comment: is this a one off thing or something you are looking to use across multiple parts of the app?

Comment: I only want to use it once in this project, but also want to do it in the pretty way so that I can reuse it maybe somewhere else that I needed the same thing. you know?

Comment: Best thing to do is probably use a custom view. If  you don't have any experience with it perhaps try this: https://www.intertech.com/Blog/android-custom-view-tutorial-part-1-combining-existing-views/ the existing views one might work; each "bar" could theoretically be just a simple View with same width and varying heights, and background colour. Then each word could be a TextView. Alternatively, you could use @SushobhNadiger answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Its actually pretty simple to create your own bar chart.

First you need to use [drawRect](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawRect(float,%20float,%20float,%20float,%20android.graphics.Paint)) to draw a rectangle.

And then [drawText](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawText(java.lang.CharSequence,%20int,%20int,%20float,%20float,%20android.graphics.Paint)) to draw text below the rectangle.

You may have noticed that both methods take a paint object as the parameter , you can think of the paint object like a brush. So you set the color to the brush and draw different elements.

I have written about it

[here](https://androidoverride.wordpress.com/2017/04/23/creating-a-custom-animated-bar-graph-in-android/)